# How to add page links to svg circle?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have 5 circles and I need to add links to them

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap your circles with `a`-tags, like you would do with most of the other elements in a html-document.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <a href="/link1">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
    </a>
    <a href="/link2">
        <circle cx="125" cy="50" r="25"/>
    </a>
    <a href="/link3">
        <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="25"/>
    </a>
</svg>
```